# Describe a Turing Machine that accepts the language of all non-negative decimal integers that are multiples of 3.

Tags: automata, turing-machines

I have exam coming up and I need help with this:

Describe a Turing Machine that accepts the language of all non-negative decimal integers that are multiples of 3

Thank you :)

Comment: How would you determine if a number was divisible by $3$?

Comment: Answering Thomas's question would be a good start.  Do you know a standard way to determine whether a decimal number is divisible by 3?

Answer (score 1):

HINTS:

1. See the suggestion made in the comments by Thomas and Tara. If you’re not familiar with divisibility tests, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule); this is useful general information.
2. This language is regular: it can be recognized by a finite state automaton. Try designing that first and then converting it to a Turing machine.